# most stable version of spring-framework

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-data

We are using spring 3.1 in our application and wants to upgrade latest version.Can somebody please confirm Which is the most stable version of spring-framework currently.

Comment: Ehrm the latest final release. 4.3.9.. What else would be the most stable?

Comment: @Akib You could have just visited the Spring website and find it yourself.

Comment: Yes obviously i checked spring website first. Just wanted to know the users experience.

Comment: The verbatim question is obviously answered by the Spring website. The last comment makes it opinion based. Either way, I'm voting to close it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Spring website](https://projects.spring.io/spring-framework/), it is `4.3.9.RELEASE`.

Answer (score 1):

You can see the latest release versions that are available through Maven here:
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-core

This link also provides the latest release for every major version of Spring (the website seemed to only provide the latest release version of the latest major version).